# Perl ipc using pipe to initiate the execution of one process from another process

Tags: perl

I want to initiate the execution of one process from another process in Perl such that the two processes run asynchronously where the parent process should not wait for the completion of execution of child process.

*So I was using pipe mechanism* [ open($fh, '-|', "./child.pl") ] to fork a new child process for child.pl from another parent process where i am using this open function to create a pipe.

The newly forked child process should continue it's execution till the parent process executes.

**But the issue what I am facing is that the child starts execution** when it is forked by using pipe but it stops writing to the pipe handles prematurely before the parent process finishes it's execution.

So how to prevent premature stop of writing to the pipe handles by child process using the pipe mechanism mentioned above such that the child process continues to write to the pipe handles for that much time the parent process executes?

Answer (score 1):

You could use IPC::Open3 to do this:

```
 my($wtr, $rdr, $err);
 use Symbol 'gensym'; $err = gensym;
 my $pid = open3($wtr, $rdr, $err,'some cmd and args', 'optarg', ...);
 ### Do something in the main prg
 waitpid( $pid, 0 );#when you no longer needs the child
 my $child_exit_status = $? >> 8;
```